# Dependent combobox list based on the other combo box Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm soo beginner in programming and I've been trying a lot so far. I have one question which might be easy for you. I've been looking for the answer but i cannot understand their solution.

My question is :

I have two combo box. (Combo Box 1 and Combo Box 2). Both Combo Box value has a list of value. Like below :

```
Combo Box 1 list             Combo Box 2 list
A                                    A1
B                                    A2
C                                    B1
D                                    B2
                                     C1
                                     D1
```

What i want is, if combo box 1 value = A, in the combo box 2 will only show a list of A1 and A2.

What i've tried is by creating a new sheet. I organize every list of Combo BOx 1 with their corresponding Combo Box 2 value should be. Like so

```
|A|      |B|        |C|         |D|
A1        B1         C1          D1
A2        B2
```

And then i run a while loop. If combobox1 value equal to the header. Then, it will add the data below the header into the combo box 2.

like so

```
j = 1
While ComboBox3.Value <> Sheets("Data2").Cells(1, j)
j = j + 1
Wend
ComboBox4.List = Sheets("Data2").Range(j).Value
```

But it seems to not working at all.

Comment: `Sheets("Data2").Range(cells(j,4),cells(j+1,4))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim r, c As Range
Set r = Sheet2.Range("A6:A100")
ComboBox2.Clear
For Each c In r
 If c.Value <> "" Then
   If Left(c, 1) Like ComboBox1.Value Then
     ComboBox2.AddItem c.Value
   End If
 End If
 Next c
```

End Sub